# How do I keep objects hidden/shown when switching between animated actions?

Tags: animation, visibility

I've a character who wields a two-handed sword. I've animated 2 walk cycles, one with weapon sheathed and another with the weapon drawn. I'm going with the approach of using two individual meshes for the sword in both positions, thinking I can hide the one that isn't in use and leave the other shown. However I'm having difficulties when switching between my actions in the action editor. Once I've keyframed the invisibility of the sheathed sword in my *weapon-drawn* walk cycle, it stays invisible in the *weapon-sheathed* walk cycle and I don't seem able to switch the visibility on and off without affecting the other walk cycle also. Is there something I'm missing or is this not possible at all?

I'm a novice, recently started making assets for games and am learning as I go. I've been stumped with this one for a couple of days now with no luck troubleshooting.

In fact, As I'm writing this, I've somehow bunged this up further. I can't keyframe either of the sword visibilities without hiding the character armature and both swords at once now.

Is there an easy way to do this??

Also wondering how to use the IK/FK arm setup to the same effect. Any help would be great.

[image: keyframing visibility selects several]

[image: Both swords and main armature disappear]